# Utility of both players in St. Petersbourg paradox - behavioural economics

Tags: utility, statistics, expected-utility, behavioral-economics

Im reading a paper by Karl Menger [1] about the St. Peterbourg paradox :

> In the theory of probability, the "Petersburg Game" designates the
> follow- ing gamei between two persons, A and B. Initially, A requires
> that B place a certain bet with A. Then they flip a coin. If it shows
> heads, then B receives 1 dollar from A, and the game is over. If it
> shows tails, it is flipped again. If the second throw turns up heads,
> then B receives 2 dollars from A, and the game ends. The coin is
> flipped until heads appears for the first time. If this happens at the
> nth throw (that is, if the first n - 1 throws aII come up tails, but
> the nth throw is heads), then B receives 2n - 1 dollars from A and the
> game ends. Depending on whether n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , B wins 2° = 1,21
> = 2,22 = 4, 23 = 8, ... dollars. What bet should B be willing to make? What is B's mathematical expectation?

his point is that the paradox does not rely on a mathematical expectation of infinite value, but on the discrepancy between the behavior of the player B and the expected result: in real life, normal people (Menger says) would not commit an infinite amount of money, in spite of expectation being mathematically infinite.

The lottery is always presented in terms that A will pay to B.
But the lottery never takes into consideration the expected value for A in committing the game.

- Which is the expected value of player A, in playing the Petersbourg game and risking to pay a sum to B ? Will A have a chance to win something ? Or is player A completely disregarded ?

[1] Karl Menger, The Role Of Uncertainty In Economics, 1979.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Will A have a chance to win something ? Yes, if the number of throws n is such that $2^{n -1}<K$ where K is the bet.  But this is obvious.  Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: It is written that B places a certain bet with A: the game ends when B wins, and the coin keeps on being flipped until B wins. So I did not understand what for you it is obvious: is the Bet the prize at each throw, or is it the maximum number of throws that can be done by betting 1 dollar at each time ?
E.g. 
Say B wins with heads, and bet is 3 dollars. After 3 throws, the expected value should it be: `1/2*1^0 + 1/2*2^1 + 1/2 * 2^2`  Or `1/2* 3^0 + 1/2* 3^1 + 1/2 * 3^2`? If the bet is 3 dollar, A wins after 2 throws if both had tails, assuming each 1 dollar is bet at each throw ?

Comment: No I think B bets an amount only once, before any coins are flipped.  The ‘paradox’ is that B’s expected value is theoretically infinite, but in real life B would not pay unlimited amounts to play this game.

Comment: So, if B bets 1 dollars and heads does not show in the first 1 tosses, A would never win, right ? 

(1 -  1/2)^0 + (1- 1/2) ^1 + (1 - 1/2) ^2 + ...] => 1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + .. ] => which is never 2−1<. 

Instead, we can calculate how many tosses A may win if the bet > 1, correct ?

Can you unpack your suggestion, I thought A's expected value would be (1 - the probability B has to win) * the value for A,  but I am still in doubt how to calculated the value for A at each toss.